# Master New Beer List

Tags: style, pairing

Is there a site that attempts to list new beers as they become available? I am always hearing about new beers from friends but I want to know when a brewery markets a new brew without having to go to everyone's site myself... Thanks!

**Edit:** Originally, I was thinking just a list of the national/international 'major' brews but I suppose even a local list (that is accurate/updated) would be helpful if visiting a certain area. The scope of this question is really just a general list of major brews.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a site dedicated to that purpose specifically. However, [Untapped](https://untappd.com/) and [Beermenus](http://www.beermenus.com/) are probably your best bets. I've never used Untapped as I do not have a smartphone and I think they've just recently added desktop/laptop support, but I have used Beermenus. It's ok, not great though. Again, it's really up to the brewery/bar to update their menu and sometimes they just forget; they're human too, despite being able to brew some godly beers.

But in general, this question is a bit too broad. in my opinion. You don't specify whether or not you're talking about local beers or just beers in general. There's a few thousand breweries worldwide; many of them coming out with new releases regularly. Keeping tabs on all of them would be somewhat of a challenge (especially the ones who don't update their sites regularly ([ahem...if my local friends across the bay are on here, I'm looking at you](http://www.fireislandbeer.com/)). So in terms of local beers, Untapped and Beermenus should do what you're looking for. But At this point in time, I think a global list is infeasible until somebody develops an easy-to-use API which gets some traction in the industry.

Comment: Thanks! I figured there probably wasnt one because of the complexity of keeping tabs on it. I'm still going to keep it open in case someone else has any other sites. Oh and I would love the site to encompass both local and major brews but I understand it is far more difficult to get those local breweries on board.

Answer (score 2):

Using the BeerAdvocate web site could be very helpful. As a craft beer enthusiast, I've used it on my travels.

Start your search at the following URL: http://www.beeradvocate.com/place/

You can break down your search results by Continent, Country, City and State. You may be able to find some local breweries that fit your liking.

Also, you can stay on top of all the latest beer release news by going to the following forum: http://www.beeradvocate.com/community/forums/beer-releases.38/

If you're not sure what you like, be sure to check out the Top 250 beers section of the Web Site to learn about some highly reviewed beers.

Comment: This kind of reads more like a letter (or worse, spam), than an answer to a question.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance wax. I've been a longtime viewer but non participant in SE. I'll do research on ways to improve my answers. Can you offer any personal insight?

Comment: Axe the greeting and signature. Probably everything after the Forum link could go too tbh.

Comment: Very valuable. Cheers

Comment: I didnt see this before it was edited but it looks good to me and I appreciate the advice in any case.